# Using Binomial Theorem for concert reservations

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Q
A concert organiser observes that 3% of those making reservations for a concert do not show up for that concert. Based on this the organiser sells 100 seats for a venue with 97 seats. Use the binomial distribution to compute the probability that there will be a seat available for each person (with a reservation) who shows up for the concert.

Attempt

> N = 100 seats
> P = 0.97 (Probability of People Showing Up)
> Q = 0.03
> (Probability of People not Showing Up)
>
> P(x < 97) = (97 + 0.1 = 100(0.97) / √100(0.97)(0.03)
>
> I get syntax error so I'm guessing this is completely wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: You get a syntax error?  Is this a programming question?

Comment: "*I get syntax error*"  Yes, what you have written certainly doesn't parse... you have mismatched number of parentheses and an equals sign inside of a parenthesis, etc...

Comment: As for what to do... as the problem tells you to do... *use the binomial distribution*!  It looks like you are trying (*and failing*) to use the *normal approximation* of the binomial distribution... which you shouldn't need to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Set $X$ the rv "number of person not showing up at the concert", your probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq 3]=1-\mathbb{P}[X=0]-\mathbb{P}[X=1]-\mathbb{P}[X=2]$$

can you conclude by yourself?